# FIleNotFoundExeption whe request from googleapis to make AutoTextComplete

Tags: java, android, google-api, filenotfoundexception

I try to make AutoTextCOmplete to show near place from my location and i found tutorial at http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-google-places-api/. its a good tutorial and give no error when being run. When i write 2 letter, i see a flash of the autotextcomplete work, but i can't see what's in it because it appeared so fast. So its like i get no return value when i write something in the AutoTextComplete field and when i input "space" character from my keyboard i get this Error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=30.7333,76.7794&rankby=distance&name=Jamu &key=[I put my key here]
>   at adapter.MyPlacesAdapter.getPlaces(MyPlacesAdapter.java:126)

and

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.StringBuffer.toString()' on a null object reference
>   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)

This is how i request it

```
private ArrayList<MyGooglePlaces> getPredictions(String constraint)
{
    //pass your current latitude and longitude to find nearby and ranky=distance means places will be found in ascending order
    // according to distance
    double latitude=30.7333;
    double longitude=76.7794;
    String API_KEY="My API Key";
    String url= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longitude+"&rankby=distance&name="+constraint+"&key="+API_KEY;
    return getPlaces(url);
}
```

This is the full Adapter code

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Created by coderzpassion on 05/03/16.
 */
public class MyPlacesAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context con;
 ArrayList<MyGooglePlaces> places=new ArrayList<MyGooglePlaces>();
    public MyPlacesAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        con=context;
    }
    // get total count of array
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return places.size();
    }
    //get item id
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    // get Mygoogleplaces object at given position
    @Override
    public MyGooglePlaces getItem(int position) {
        return places.get(position);
    }
    //Filter to filter the results
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter=new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
               FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
                if(constraint!=null)
                {
                  places=getPredictions(constraint.toString());
                    if(places!=null)
                    {
                        results.values=places;
                        results.count=places.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
    // method to get different places nearby search location
    private ArrayList<MyGooglePlaces> getPredictions(String constraint)
    {
        //pass your current latitude and longitude to find nearby and ranky=distance means places will be found in ascending order
        // according to distance
        double latitude=30.7333;
        double longitude=76.7794;
        String API_KEY="AIzaSyByodZEsDBTC-J3brJ39JiYTkqbtJhlSKo";
      String url= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longitude+"&rankby=distance&name="+constraint+"&key="+API_KEY;
          return getPlaces(url);
    }
    private ArrayList<MyGooglePlaces> getPlaces(String constraint)
    {
        //code for API level 23 as httpclient is depricated in API 23
        StringBuffer sb=null;
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(constraint);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = isw.read();
             sb=new StringBuffer("");
            while (data != -1) {
                sb.append((char)data);
                //char current = (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
               // System.out.print(current);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
      return   parseGoogleParse(sb.toString());
    }
// method to parse the json returned by googleplaces api
    private static ArrayList parseGoogleParse(final String response) {
        ArrayList<MyGooglePlaces> temp = new ArrayList();
        try {
            // make an jsonObject in order to parse the response
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            // make an jsonObject in order to parse the response
            if (jsonObject.has("results")) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    MyGooglePlaces poi = new MyGooglePlaces();
                    if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("name")) {
                        poi.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("name"));
                        poi.setRating(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("rating", " "));
                        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("opening_hours")) {
                            if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("opening_hours").has("open_now")) {
                                if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("opening_hours").getString("open_now").equals("true")) {
                                    poi.setOpenNow("YES");
                                } else {
                                    poi.setOpenNow("NO");
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            poi.setOpenNow("Not Known");
                        }
                        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("geometry"))
                        {
                            if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").has("location"))
                            {
                                if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").has("lat"))
                                {
                                    poi.setLatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat")), Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng")));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("vicinity")) {
                            poi.setVicinity(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("vicinity"));
                        }
                        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("types")) {
                            JSONArray typesArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("types");
                            for (int j = 0; j < typesArray.length(); j++) {
                                poi.setCategory(typesArray.getString(j) + ", " + poi.getCategory());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //if(temp.size()<5)
                        temp.add(poi);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ArrayList();
        }
        return temp;
    }
    // View method called for each row of the result
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder;
        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete, null);
            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myplaces);
            holder.address=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // If weren't re-ordering this you could rely on what you set last time
        holder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+places.get(position).getName()+"<b>"));
        holder.address.setText(places.get(position).getVicinity());
        return convertView;
    }
  // viewholder class to hold adapter views
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text,address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to see code how you are setting adapter. You should call Network related operations in separate thread. This might be the reason your are getting NullPointerException because data is not available yet.

Comment: I already updated my post with my complete Adapter... Please help me... @FaizanMubasher